# regarding using sys.path.insert and import multiple path information contained in a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In [demo.py](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/KittiSeg/blob/master/demo.py) of this project, there is one line of code `sys.path.insert(1, 'incl')`. After running this line of code, we can see that `sys.path` has added one more extra item `'incl'`. As shown from the [github project](https://github.com/MarvinTeichmann/KittiSeg), we can see there is a subfolder named as `'incl'` containing some path information. I can guess that with the help of sys.path.insert, we should be able to include these path information, but running from seg_utils import seg_utils as seg fails by giving the error message of. My estimation is that `'incl'` was not correctly imported into `sys.path`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo.py", line 52, in <module>
from seg_utils import seg_utils as seg
```

ImportError: No module named seg_utils

Comment: Hmm, this worked fine for me. What is your operating system, and how are you invoking `demo.py`?

Comment: I created Anaconda virtual environment on RedHat linux. The Python is of 2.7.13.  I was not able to run git clone and git submodule update due to the fact that I am using an enterprise network behind firewall. I just download the project as a zip and expand it in the working directory.  I invoke demo.py as python demo.py --input_image data/demo/demo.png